# Micronaut ApplicationContextBuilder NoSuchMethod error

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client

I'm trying to migrate my service from Micronaut 1 to 3. It's working in Micronaut 1 but when upgrading the libraries to Micronaut 3, I encounter the issue below. I'm using AWS Lambda but Lambda is failing upon startup:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext.build([Ljava/lang/String;)Lio/micronaut/context/ApplicationContextBuilder;",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "io.micronaut.function.executor.AbstractExecutor.newApplicationContextBuilder(AbstractExecutor.java:105)",
    "io.micronaut.function.executor.AbstractExecutor.buildApplicationContext(AbstractExecutor.java:80)",
    "io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler.buildApplicationContext(MicronautRequestHandler.java:77)",
    "io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler.handleRequest(MicronautRequestHandler.java:45)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
    "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
    "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
  ]
}
```

pom.xml (dependencies)

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-function-aws</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
          <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
          <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
          <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-codec-http2</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.636</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-lambda</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.636</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.636</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ph.samson.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-luhn-mask</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
      <artifactId>nv-i18n</artifactId>
      <version>1.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>32.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
      <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-function-client</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-function-web</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <version>1.11.636</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <version>1.11.636</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
<!--    jackson -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-cbor</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.94.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.94.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.94.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-codec-http2</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.94.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.94.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-handler-proxy</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.94.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.94.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.94.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Is there an incompatible library version that I'm using? TIA

Comment: I don't think your dependencies are causing the error. Please provide your Application class code.

Comment: You have Lombok in your deps, hence I guess this is all Java. Please have a look at Micronaut OpenRewrite that may help you with the upgrade. https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/micronaut